# ngx-scanner-qrcode reading data in TS

Tags: javascript, angular, qr-code

I'm trying to read data from QR code that i generated online, using **ngx-scanner-qrcode**
so far i'm able by following the same code provided in the example to show the data in html but I don't know how to read it in TS file. I will really appreciate if someone can help with this it might be easy but i'm still joiner.

Here is the example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-scanner-qrcode?file=src/app/app.component.html

I tried to read all the data from the res that I will get once the file is uploaded but still not showing the data that it's showing in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

At version 1.0.25 it has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's getting the data now in the TS :)